# The duration of Christ's ministry?

Tags: gospels, christology

The conventional wisdom has been that Christ's ministry lasted somewhere in the range of 3 to 3.5 years, although Dr. Chilton suggested, according to the Gospel of John, that Christ's ministry was closer to 1 year in length in [Rabbi Jesus: An Intimate Biography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000FC1K4I).

My question is, apart from Dr. Chilton's assertion, what is the proof from the Gospels (Synoptics and/or John) that Christ's ministry lasted only 3 to 3.5 years? Is there any reason to think it lasted longer?

I realize that His ministry began when He was about [30 years of age](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?qs_version=KJV&quicksearch=thirty&begin=49&end=49), at the time of His baptism, but I can't reckon from the Gospels that from that point forward there were only 3 to 3.5 years to the Cross. It seems like an assumption that fits certain theological or eschatological models but isn't actually predicated upon the texts themselves.

So then, can anyone provide a reasonable timetable from the Gospels showing or proving that the conventional wisdom is accurate?

Comment: John’s account is of the last year primarily hence why it appears it was only a year long. The other gospels give indications why it was longer and as such there is no conflict between all four accounts.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo The beginnings of an answer, there. Hopefully, you will expand ?

Answer (score 2):

In the accounts of Jesus' ministry by John the Evangelist, we have the following references to Passover festivals/feasts:

1. John 2:13 - Jesus goes to Jerusalem; John 2:23 - many say what Jesus was doing at the Passover.  See also John 4:45 which refers to the same festival
2. John 5:1 - an unnamed "feast of the Jews" - see below
3. John 6:4 - Passover festival was near
4. John 13:1 - Passover with Jesus and disciples in the upper room.

The unnamed "feast" of the Jews (#2 above) was also likely to have been the Passover for the following reasons:

- According to Matt 4:12 and Mark 1:14, the imprisonment of John the Baptist caused Jesus to shift His ministry from Judea to Galilee
- According to Matt 14:10-21 (compare John 6:4-15) John was beheaded at Passover time one year prior to Jesus' death
- Jesus' public Galilean ministry closed at Passover one year before the crucifixion (John 5:1, 6:66).  Therefore, the Galilean ministry coincides with the period of John's imprisonment
- Jesus' Judean ministry began immediately after Passover following His baptism and last for an unspecified (but extended) time during which John was not in prison (John 3:22, 24).
- Since the event of John 3 and John 4 almost certainly last longer than 7 weeks, the feast of John 5;1 could not have been Pentecost and very likely could not have been Tabernacles.

Therefore, it is most likely that the unnamed feats of John 5:1 was another Passover.

On this basis, we have Jesus' ministry lasting longer than four Passovers and thus, His ministry was more than 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

I may have discovered a way to possibly answer my own question.

Luke 13:6-9 (KJV),

6 He spake also this parable; A certain man had a fig tree planted in his vineyard; and he came and sought fruit thereon, and found none.

7 Then said he unto the dresser of his vineyard, Behold, these three years I come seeking fruit on this fig tree, and find none: cut it down; why cumbereth it the ground?

8 And he answering said unto him, Lord, let it alone this year also, till I shall dig about it, and dung it:

9 And if it bear fruit, well: and if not, then after that thou shalt cut it down.

So, if the parable is about Israel as represented by a fig tree, (as all of Matthew 24, especially verse 32, seems to indicate) it looks like a minimum of three and a maximum of four years is the correct understanding of how long Christ's ministry lasted before the crucifixion.